# Confusion about how `create-react-app --template typescript` hooked up with typescript-eslint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I created a react project using `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`. And I found that somehow `typescript-eslint` is already enabled by default.
[image]

I checked the eslint config inside of the `package.json`

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
```

I thought in order for `typescript-eslint` to be enabled you would need either `"extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` in your `package.json` or `.eslintrc`. But in this case I cannot find either one of these in the codebase. I wonder how the eslint for typescript got enabled?

Comment: Did you look at the react-app ESLint plugin? It references that other plugin: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app

Comment: @jonrsharpe yea I looked at it but I didn't find it referencing typescript eslint plugin

Comment: ...how hard did you look? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app/index.js#L58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRA is intended to be a one-stop shop for setting up your react app. This includes build configs, folder structures, and everything required to develop a react app with the best practices.

Whilst not really explicitly listed anywhere, CRA comes with a preconfigured linting experience using the `eslint-config-react-app` config.

On their main page, they mention:

> [Under the hood, we use webpack, Babel, ***ESLint***, and other amazing projects to power your app.](https://create-react-app.dev/) (emphasis mine)

It's also mentioned in places like the IDE experience, but in a "you should already know this is a thing" kind of way:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor

---

For typescript projects, the CRA config ofc includes tooling from the `@typescript-eslint` project, as it is the standard for linting typescript code.

Without using this project, they would run into many issues attempting to lint typescript codebases (the biggest being that it wouldn't work at all).

The above docs contain information about how you can further configure your linting experience if you want.